# get width of a dynamic tabpanel's header span of ajax tabcontainer in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, tabcontainer

I am debugging asp.net web page to make it look like Internet Explorer IE11 where closing the last tab will bring the close button of the previous tab to the mouse position. My tabcontainer has tabs with spans in it.

I tried this one:

```
var i=1;var count=1;
         function removeAt(tabPanelClientID, index) {
             if (index == i)
             {
                 var prevTabPanel = $get('__tab_TabContainerMain_TabPanel' + (index - 1));
                 alert('ptp=' + prevTabPanel+' width='+prevTabPanel.style.width);
             }
             count--;
     }
```

the output is 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viRx8.png).

`prevTabPanel.style.width` didn't work. How to get width of the tab panel's header?
Thanks in advance
**EDIT:**
I tried it with `prevTabPanel.width();` I got error as 'undefined'

Comment: In Visual studio 2010, when mouse hovers over the heading in design view, it shows a tooltip with width and height

Comment: hover the mouse over the resizing bubbles of a control in Visual studio 2012 , height and width are displayed